# Цикл for печатает в неправильном порядке

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Короче говоря, делаю генератор ASCII-art для букв. Проблема с циклами: печатает оно правильно, только в неправильном порядке. У цикла внутри второй цикл, который предполагается должен печатать по одной строке от каждой буквы.

Пробовал менять циклы местами и переставлять переменные... Что я делаю не так?

Массив букв:

```java
String[][] letters =
{{
        " █████╗ ",
        "██╔══██╗",
        "███████║",
        "██╔══██║",
        "██║  ██║",
        "╚═╝  ╚═╝"
},{
        "██████╗ ",
        "██╔══██╗",
        "██████╔╝",
        "██╔══██╗",
        "██████╔╝",
        "╚═════╝ "
}};
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
 █████╗  ██████╗ 
██╔══██╗ ██╔══██╗
███████║ ██████╔╝
██╔══██║ ██╔══██╗
██║  ██║ ██████╔╝
╚═╝  ╚═╝ ╚═════╝
```

Мой код:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < letters[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println(letters[i][j]);
    }
}
```

На выходе получается это:

```
 █████╗ 
██╔══██╗
███████║
██╔══██║
██║  ██║
╚═╝  ╚═╝
██████╗ 
██╔══██╗
██████╔╝
██╔══██╗
██████╔╝
╚═════╝
```

Comment: Насколько я помню, println печатает с переносом на следующую строку. А вот print печатает без переноса

Comment: `println` - как бы намекает что любой вывод будет с новой строки. используйте обычный `print`, а перенос строки делайте тогда, когда нужно!

Answer (score 3):

Нужно идти построчно по всем буквам, сначала вывести все первые строки всех букв, потом все вторые и т.д.:

```
// Считаем что в массиве есть хотя бы одна буква, и количество строк в буквах одинаково
for (int j = 0; j < letters[0].length; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(letters[i][j]);  // print вместо println, чтобы не добавлялся перенос строки
        System.out.print(" ");  // Пробел между буквами, чтобы они не сливались
    }
    System.out.println("");  // Перенос строки после вывода каждой строки всех букв
}
```

По сути поменялись местами циклы (цикл по строкам стал внешним, цикл по буквам - внутренним) и способ вывода.

Результат:

```
 █████╗  ██████╗  
██╔══██╗ ██╔══██╗ 
███████║ ██████╔╝ 
██╔══██║ ██╔══██╗ 
██║  ██║ ██████╔╝ 
╚═╝  ╚═╝ ╚═════╝
```

https://ideone.com/4D5Wue

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Symbol {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <String> ar = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] letterA ={
                    " █████╗ ",
                    "██╔══██╗",
                    "███████║",
                    "██╔══██║",
                    "██║  ██║",
                    "╚═╝  ╚═╝"};
        String[] letterB ={
                    "██████╗ ",
                    "██╔══██╗",
                    "██████╔╝",
                    "██╔══██╗",
                    "██████╔╝",
                    "╚═════╝ "};
        // массивы-->ArrayList
        ArrayList <String> letters = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(letterA));ar.addAll(letters);
        letters = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(letterB));ar.addAll(letters);
        // ArrayList-->массив
        String []letterss = ar.toArray(new String[0]);
        
        for(int i =0;i<letterss.length/2;i++) {// --> AB
            System.out.println(letterss[i]+"\s"+letterss[(letterss.length/2)+i]);
        }
    };
}
```

только с одномерными массивами нашел решение)) ,зато их теперь удобно заводить в общий массив